# Why is Alembic running the wrong migration script?

Tags: alembic

When I try

```
alembic upgrade head
```

Alembic runs the previous migration script, obviously raising an error because my schema has changed.

In my database, I have `version_num` set to `48957fdfe8d5`. After running

```
alembic revision -m '<my message>'
```

Alembic created the new script file—the one I want to run—with this at the top

```
revision = '28cc06993b73'
down_revision = '4d5f9ba76c5e'
```

In other words, everything looks good. So why is it clearly running the code in `4d5f9ba76c5e` rather than `28cc06993b73`? I have also tried

```
alembic upgrade 28cc06993b73
```

But it still runs the code in `4d5f9ba76c5e`. Here is that log:

```
$ alembic upgrade 28cc06993b73
INFO  [alembic.migration] Context impl MySQLImpl.
INFO  [alembic.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
Starting in DEBUG mode
INFO  [alembic.migration] Running upgrade 48957fdfe8d5 -> 4d5f9ba76c5e, Breaking up metadata into required and optional
```

Also, if I check Alembic's history, I see that head is on `28cc06993b73`:

```
$ alembic history
Starting in DEBUG mode
4d5f9ba76c5e -> 28cc06993b73 (head), creating soft file table
48957fdfe8d5 -> 4d5f9ba76c5e, Breaking up metadata into required and optional
<base> -> 48957fdfe8d5, Init
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly you said that your version number is 48957fdfe8d5 in the db so  an upgrade from 48957fdfe8d5 -> 4d5f9ba76c5e is expected based on your alembic history.

You also say "Alembic runs the previous migration script, obviously raising an error because my schema has changed." What error is it showing?  Did you manually change the db so that it reflects what is supposed to happen in 28cc06993b73?  If that is the case then you could run

```
alembic stamp head
```

to get your db in sync with alembic migrations